# Selecting multiple users and sending them an invite

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I apologise if there is a similar post to this that I haven't found, I can only see ones for Facebook API. If you know of a post, please do point me in the right direction, thanks.

**What I am wanting to do is....**

Allow a user to invite any member to his/her event by selecting them from a list (Multiple selection, possibly with JQuery) and sending the invite.

**I understand the theory behind what I have to...**

1. Have the list of  users displayed dynamically in a table *(I know how to do that)*
2. Allow each user to be selected. *(Don't know how to do that in JQuery)*
3. Then, when you click on a user, their user id is put into an array
   of some kind *(Might need help with that)*
4. Then when the invite button is submitted, the ids are put into a database table called 
   invitations along with the id of the event they are being invited to. 
   *(I know how to do that)*

I've had a look on jquery.com but as I'm not by any means an expert at it I'm not really sure on what I need to do. If you need to know anything else, please ask.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

edit: Should probably add, my database is MySQL and I'm coding in PHP.

Comment: Go and learn a language .... have a go ... then when you get stuck - come back on here and post some code and ask people to look at the problem ...

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form element, put your table within the form. Create checkboxes on each table row td. Checkbox value is that of the user's ID.

use Jquery to serialize the checkboxes and submit a serialized form to a php script to do the backend leg work...

```
  $('#submit-form-button').click(function(){
    var checkboxes = $('.checkboxes').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'processInvites.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {checkBoxes: checkboxes},
      success: function(data){
        console.log("Form was successful");
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log("Form was a failure");
      }
    });
  });
```

Use PHP to explode the serialized array..
Should note you can  reference urldecode() in the php manual and it has a similar statement at the bottom of the manual,  just before the comments.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
$c = explode('&', $_POST['checkBoxes']);
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($c)){
  $b = explode('=', $c[$i]);
  $checkBox[] = urldecode($b[1]);
  $i++;
}
```

and verify that it exists in the db..

```
$listOfUsers = //SQL HERE TO GET ARRAY OF USERS IDs IN KEY => VALUE FORM.

foreach ($checkBox as $c){
  if(in_array($c, $listOfUsers){
    //INSERT USER ID IN INVITATIONS TABLE
    //SQL HERE, MAKE SURE TO XSS FILTER YOUR POST INPUTS
  }else{
    //User isnt in database, do something else. 
    // don't return false or fail because you want to continue processing
    // write to a log file?
  }
}
```

I have not tested this, but i use the exact same concept for a different application of selecting a list of "Categories" and pulling back rows from db that are equal to that categories ID..

Comment: oooh ok. I think I get it. Thanks for that! I'll give it a try.

Comment: added a link to urldecode(), so you can reference more info.